# Android, view background selector, what is the proper way to do my task?

Tags: android, view, selector

I have EditText, which may be in 3 states:

1) Enabled, correct input

2) Enabled, incorrect input

3) Disabled

I have 3 background drawables, each corresponds to each state. How to show proper drawable for each state? I would like to accomplish this task with selector. Something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled"/>
     <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/enbaled_correct_input"/>
</selector>
```

But how do I identify selector item, which corresponds to "Enabled, incorrect input"? I need one more state. I could extend EditText, create custom state and use it in selector, but this seemes to be overkill for my task (I only use this selector once in application).

Alternatively, I could invoke setBackgroundResource in code and pass proper backgrounds for proper states, but this means rejecting selector. I would like to accomplish this task with selector and without extending EditText and new view state. Yes, I'm lazy :) How to do this?

Comment: create a StateListDrawable and call se5State when data is valid/invalid

Comment: Which exactly state should I pass?

Comment: disabled; enabled and your custom one

Comment: Do you mean, I can declare custom state and use it with any view by means of StateListDrawable?

Comment: ok that is tricky a bit: give me ten minutes and i will answer with different but better solution

Comment: done, see my answer, try to type something in EditText and then clear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this custom drawable (res/drawable/et.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/disabled" />
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <level-list>
    <item android:minLevel="0" android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/invalid" />
    <item android:minLevel="1" android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/valid" />
    </level-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

testing code:

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.et);
    et.setEnabled(false);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("enabled / disabled");
    ll.addView(et);
    ll.addView(b);
    setContentView(ll);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et.setEnabled(!et.isEnabled());
        }
    });

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            et.getBackground().setLevel(s.length() == 0? 0 : 1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think it is something, I've been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

create two different selectors and depending on input switch selector programmatically.

pseudo:

```
   if(mEditTextBooleanCorrect)
      mEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mySelectorCorrect)
   else
      mEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mySelectorIncorrect)
```

EDIT: Do this in a OnTextChangedListener

Comment: This is how I am doing it now. However, I would like to join that into one single selector. If possible.

Comment: It's possible but not worth the effort, you would have to override the selector for edittext, the way you're doing it now is by far the simplest and best, don't overcomplicate things ;)

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected, is this more memory efficient though? And does it even need to be on an EditText. The code gets less obvious of what it does, so for readability it's a minus. It did answer his question though so kudos to you

Comment: @PontusBacklund one selector is more memory efficient that two, moreover think of inner  LevelListDrawable as a container that can hold more than two extra sub-states Drawable can have, you can add another two or more sub-states while in your solution you will have to add two more selectors

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve it via the selector mechanism as it's not possible to define new states and bind them to XML attributes in a selector.

Nevertheless, you don't need to extend TextView to validate it. The idea is to use a `TextWatcher` :

```
txt1.addTextChangedListener(validator);
```

where you validator will override the method

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    validate(textView, text);
}
```

Then the validate method could call setBackgroundResource to switch from one color to another depending on validation. When you enable your textview, you should call validate as well.

And apart of that particular state management, I would rely on XML.

Comment: In essense, I am doing it now. But I would like to get rid of setBackgroundResource calls in code. I believe the best way is to do all the stuff in xml and only change states in code (explicitly or implicitly). However, it seemes, there is no easy solution to this problem.

Comment: Not exactly, the problem you try to solve is solved. But the solution you wanted is just not feasible.